# Creating a new parameter based on a logic in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My MySQL table contains 2 fields and I want to create a "new parameter" based on a logic to apply `ORDER BY 'new parameter'` function in MySQL.

My logic to create the "new parameter":

```
+------------+------------+
| field1     |  field2    |
+------------+------------+
| 100        |            |
| 101        |            |
| 103        | 101        |
| 105        |            |
| 110        | 100        |
| 115        | 110        |
| 116        | 100        |
+------------+------------+
```

Logic:

```
If 'field2' is NULL then take 'field1' value
Else take 'field2' value
```

after applying this logic "new parameter" will contain these values for each row in the table:

```
100
101
101
105
100
110
100
```

How can I do this in MySQL/PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COALESCE(Field2, Field1) = 'Blah Blah'
```

The [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) Function will move through its list of fields/values until it finds a non DBNULL value. COALESCE can also be used in the Return Section of a Statement.

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field2, Field1) as NewParam FROM TABLE
```